# Mensagem de erro: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: package not installed?"

Tags: android, eclipse

#### Situação

Estou recebendo este tipo de erro no meu *logcat* e não sei exatamente o que pode ser. Embora este erro não esteja comprometendo o funcionamento da aplicação (pelo que se percebe) sendo compilado partir do **Eclipse**, o projeto ainda continua executando normalmente. Este projeto não consta no **Google Play Store**, porém ele possui um servidor para controle de versão. Sempre que é gerado uma nova versão da aplicação, automaticamente ele recebe uma notificação constando que possui esta nova versão para ser instalada.

#### Mensagem

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate 
application android.app.Application: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for br.com.meuapp; 
is package not installed?
```

#### Momento do erro

O erro aparece exatamente após a compilação do código para gerar um novo `.apk` para reinstalação usando *USB Debug*.

#### Configuração do Ambiente

- IDE: [Eclipse Mars 2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Mars/2)
- SDK Target: [Android 2.3.3 - Api Level 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.3.html)
- Dispositivo de Teste: [Smartphone Lenovo Vibe A7010](http://www.lenovovibe.com.br/smartphone-lenovo-vibe-A7010#specifications)

#### Observação

No projeto está sendo utilizado a permissão `INSTALL_PACKAGES` no qual, por padrão é exibida uma mensagem de erro que só é possível compilar se executar o <kbd>CLEAN</kbd> do projeto.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

> Permission is only granted to system apps

#### Dúvidas

Preciso  que estas dúvidas seja esclarecidas em relação ao erro, pois pode vir acontecer algum crash em outro dispositivo que não seja o de teste.

Qual a causa deste erro? O que pode acontecer se o erro persistir? Como corrigir este erro?

Comment: Já aconteceu comigo, e resolvi indo em **Build/Clean Project**, assim a IDE realoca tudo no seu devido lugar.

Comment: @LeonardoDias Você fez isso no Android Studio? Eu uso o Eclipse, que neste caso seria equivalente Project/Clean... porém não resolve o problema! Acontece exatamente quando o aplicativo está aberto usando USB Debug, ai eu executo para instalar novamente. Aí no logcat mostra a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Você está mesmo enfrentado esse problema ou copiou a pergunta [daqui](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24426635/2556111)?

Comment: @ramaral se eu disser que é as duas opções você acredita? Pois bem, quando eu vou fazer uma pergunta, o normal é fazer uma pesquisa. Encontrei algumas coisas que não me convenceu no entendimento. Então fiz das dívida dois outros a minha também. Mas resumindo, estou de fato com este problema. Porém como não está afetando meu projeto, resolvi ter um pouco mais de paciência.

Comment: Sim acredito. Há algo mais que possa acrescentar à pergunta? Você tem alguma suspeita do que possa ser?

Comment: @ramaral eu editei a questão inserindo o **Momento do erro**. Eu não tenho muito mais detalhes em questão.

Comment: @ramaral dei uma melhorada no texto para melhor entendimento da questão. Pelo que percebo, talvez tem alguma coisa a ver com o controle de versão da aplicação. Mas não tenho certeza! Daí então, estou ainda fazendo pesquisas para resolver o problema para que eu não tenha alguma dor de cabeça no futuro.

Comment: Eu achei uma pergunta no [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24426790/2456894) similar, segundo a resposta aceita se voce desinstalar a app do smartphone antes de mandar o eclipse rodar o erro não ocorre.

Comment: @seamusd a solução proposta no Stack Overflow global deu resultado e você só quer entender por que a solução é aquela *ou* ainda não solucionou o danado do erro?

Comment: @José o problema ainda ocorre na minha aplicação. Eu queria entender por qual motivo ocorre, se é um bug da IDE; se a ocorrência está relacionado exatamente a aplicação; ou até mesmo se é pelo dispositivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O motivo de conceder a permissão [`INSTALL_PACKAGES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_PACKAGES), está relacionado a instalação de aplicações silenciosamente. Se a aplicação não tiver a "permissão fontes desconhecidas" e sucessivamente não conceder permissão do `INSTALL_PACKAGES` no manifest.xml, a aplicação NÃO será instalada. Algumas aplicações ou boa parte delas tem uma opção de instalação "não assistida" ou silenciosa, conhecido como [*silent install*](http://techterms.com/definition/silent_install), que é fazer a instalação de uma aplicação sem que o usuário ou equipe de suporte precise interagir com essa aplicação em sua instalação.

> Qual a causa deste erro?

O erro acontece porque o IDE tenta reinstalar a aplicação por cima da aplicação em funcionamento, quando na verdade esta iniciativa teria que partir especificadamente a partir de uma rotina dentro do app.

> O que pode acontecer se o erro persistir?

Só acontecerá algum tipo de problema se o `.apk` localizado no *server* de versionamento não estiver assinado com mesma chave. Desta forma, a aplicação não será instalada.

> Como corrigir este erro?

Como disse na reposta a cima, não acontecerá um erro caso a aplicação tenha mesma chave.

Answer (score 1):

Cara esse error é comum em relação a versão do Android (api 10).
[Link de Error Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25869&can=1&q=LoadedApk.makeApplication&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Pelo que o vi no StackOverflow "Global" esse erro não altera em nada em relação a sua aplicação como foi dito por você acima. Más existe um solução que é tentar desinstalar o apk e instalar ele de novo.

Outra opção é se possível trocar a api de desenvolvimento.

O fato é que não tem nada em relação ao código/IDE e sim um possível bug na versão utilizada.

Comment: Não entendi qual é a relação que tem a pergunta com o link que você inseriu.

Comment: Link é sobre umas troca de palavras sobre o mesmo erro em questão que você ta tendo no Google Code. No  qual a soluções plausíveis são essas em questão que citei em cima depois da leituras do comentários.
Existe a possibilidade de trocar do Eclipse pelo AndroidStudio para fazer o Build do Apk? Se sim tenta fazer o teste.